# SQL query help - alternative to join

Tags: sql

looking to do a join where I join one table to another on for example brand and join only to the first record it comes to based on a rank I have placed on the other table. a simple example of the two tables and the output required are displayed below.

Thanks

```
Table 1                 Table 2     
brand   serial no       brand   serial no   rank
toyota  x1              toyota  c4          1
toyota  x2              toyota  c5          2
toyota  x3              toyota  c6          3


Desired output                  
toyota  x1  c4          
toyota  x2  c5          
toyota  x3  c6
```

Comment: Always the same number of rows in the tables?

Comment: no there will be different number of rows in my actual dataset. I don't need it to get to the end of the list on the second table either, just take one value each but not repeating

Comment: Add one or two rows to one of the tables, and adjust the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER` in a subquery, something like this.

Sample Data;

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1 (Brand nvarchar(10), Serial_No nvarchar(2))
INSERT INTO #Table1 (Brand, Serial_No)
VALUES 
('toyota','x1')
,('toyota','x2')
,('toyota','x3')

CREATE TABLE #Table2 (Brand nvarchar(10), Serial_No nvarchar(2), Rank_No int)
INSERT INTO #Table2 (Brand, Serial_No, Rank_No)
VALUES 
('toyota','c4',1)
,('toyota','c5',2)
,('toyota','c6',3)
```

Query

```
SELECT
    t1.Brand
    ,t1.Serial_No
    ,t2.Serial_No
FROM 
(SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Serial_No) Row_Num
    ,Brand
    ,Serial_No
FROM #Table1
) t1
LEFT JOIN #Table2 t2
    ON t1.Row_Num = t2.Rank_No
```

Output

```
Brand   Serial_No   Serial_No
toyota  x1          c4
toyota  x2          c5
toyota  x3          c6
```

Comment: *and thus by brute force you achieve the stated output*; but what is the business logic that dictates that a row number ordered by serial_no is the logical relationship.

Comment: I guess my point really is why give false hope that there is some magic formula to this mysterious relationship - that we can guess.

Comment: @Used_By_Already then I guess flag as "unclear what you are asking" (as I also have) and move on with the day?

Comment: A version of row number has helped allowed me to get the result I need. thanks for your help